# Extract digits in between two pipes padded with whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to use regex to find matches of the numbers between pipes  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ...} in this line ;

> | 2021-08-18 01:28 | Twitter      | [INTL TWITTER AAA BBB CC ] (https://twitter.c.xx-xx-2.aaaa.com/#/groups/123) | Twitter XX (C++, C#) | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | [ aaaa ] | 5 | 6 | 7 |

my best attemt is this one :

```
\| 2021-08-18 01:28 \| Twitter \| \[INTL TWITTER AAA BBB CC ] \(https:\/\/twitter\.c\.xx-xx-2\.aaaa\.com\/#\/groups\/123\) \| Twitter XX \(C\+\+, C#\) \| (\d+) \| (\d+) \| (\d+) \| (\d+) \| \[ aaaa ] \| (\d+) \| (\d+) \| (\d+) \|
```

It is actually working but it looks very hard coded ... If you can suggest an improvement I would be thankfull
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
\|\s*(\d+)(?=\s*\|)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1hUUp4/1). *Details*:

- `\|` - a pipe char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?=\s*\|)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and a pipe char.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ZDxolt):

```java
String s = "| 2021-08-18 01:28 | Twitter | [INTL TWITTER AAA BBB CC ] (https://twitter.c.xx-xx-2.aaaa.com/#/groups/123) | Twitter XX (C++, C#) | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | [ aaaa ] | 5 | 6 | 7 |";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|\\s*(\\d+)(?=\\s*\\|)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
} 
// => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Comment: This seems to work, many thanks. is there a way to each number in a different groupe like 1 -> group(1), 
2 -> group(2) ....

Comment: @OualidELHASNAOUI No, it is not how regexps work. Java regex does not keep a stack for its captures. This approach is based on multiple occurrence matching.

Comment: ok your suggestion will work for me @Wiktor, Thanks again and have a good day